# R: Reshaping Multiple Columns from Long to Wide

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, tidyr, reshape2

Using following data:

```
library(tidyverse)

sample_df <- data.frame(Letter = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"),
                        Number = c(1,2,1,3,4),
                        Fruit = c("Apple", "Plum", "Peach", "Pear", "Peach"))


Letter Number Fruit
a      1      Apple
a      2      Plum
a      1      Peach
b      3      Pear
b      4      Peach
```

I want to transform a set of values from a long to a wide format:

```
Letter Number_1 Number_2 Fruit_1 Fruit_2 Fruit_3
a      1        2        Apple   Plum    Peach
b      3        4        Pear    Peach
```

To do so, I unsuccessfully tried to create an index of each unique group combinations using `c("Letter", "Number")` and `c("Letter", "Fruit")`. Firstly, does this index need to be created, and if so how should it be done?

```
# Gets Unique Values, but no Index of Unique Combinations
sample_df1 <- sample_df %>%
  group_by(Letter) %>%  
  mutate(Id1 = n_distinct(Letter, Number),
         Id2 = n_distinct(Letter, Fruit))

# Gets Following Error: Column `Id1` must be length 3 (the group size) or one, not 2
sample_df1 <- sample_df %>%
  group_by(Letter) %>%  
  mutate(Id1 = 1:n_distinct(Letter, Number),
         Id2 = 1:n_distinct(Letter, Fruit))

# NOTE: Manually Created the Index Columns to show next problem
sample_df1 <- sample_df %>%
  group_by(Letter) %>%  
  add_column(Id1 = c(1,2,1,1,2),
         Id2 = c(1,2,3,1,2))
```

Assuming it did need to be done, I manually appended the desired values, and partially solved the problem using developmental [tidyr](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/pivot.html).

```
# Requires Developmental Tidyr
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr")  

sample_df1 %>%  
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("Id1", "Id2"), values_from = c("Number", "Fruit")) %>%
  set_names(~ str_replace_all(.,"(\\w+.*)(_\\d)(_\\d)", "\\1\\3"))

#  Letter Number_1 Number_2 Number_3 Fruit_1 Fruit_2 Fruit_3
#<fct>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <fct>   <fct>   <fct>  
# a         1        2        1     Apple   Plum    Peach  
# b         3        4       NA     Pear    Peach   NA
```

However, this approach still created an unwanted `Number_3` column. Using any `tidyr`, `data.table` or any other package, is there any way of getting the data in the desired format without duplicating columns?

Comment: Try `dcast(setDT(sample_df), Letter ~ rowid(Letter), value.var = c("Number", "Fruit"))`

Comment: Far more concise, but it still creates `Number_3`.

Comment: Just a doubt, regarding the combination, is it dropped becausee it doesn't have all the combinationss

Comment: No, it's dropped because while it's still in the long format, it's already covered in the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to replace the `duplicated` elements by 'Letter' to `NA` and then in the reshaped data, remove the columns that are all `NA`

```
library(data.table)
out <- dcast(setDT(sample_df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
     replace(x, duplicated(x), NA)), Letter], Letter ~ rowid(Letter), 
     value.var = c("Number", "Fruit"))
nm1 <- out[, names(which(!colSums(!is.na(.SD))))]
out[, (nm1) := NULL][]
#   Letter Number_1 Number_2 Fruit_1 Fruit_2 Fruit_3
#1:      a        1        2   Apple    Plum   Peach
#2:      b        3        4    Pear   Peach    <NA>
```

---

If we want to use the `tidyverse` approach, a similar option can be used.  Note that `pivot_wider` is from the dev version of `tidyr` (`tidyr_0.8.3.9000`)

```
library(tidyverse)
sample_df %>% 
     group_by(Letter) %>%
     mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ replace(., duplicated(.), NA)) %>%
     mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
          names_from = rn,
          values_from = c("Number", "Fruit")) %>%
  select_if(~ any(!is.na(.)))
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#  Letter Number_1 Number_2 Fruit_1 Fruit_2 Fruit_3
#  <fct>     <dbl>    <dbl> <fct>   <fct>   <fct>  
#1 a             1        2 Apple   Plum    Peach  
#2 b             3        4 Pear    Peach   <NA>
```